# How do I load mapbox in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using Next.js and their `next/script` component to load `mapbox` in a `<Map />` component. This seems to work.

**Map.js**

```
import Script from 'next/script';

export default Map() {

  const createMap = () => {
    // set access token
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...';

    // create map
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({...});
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Script
        onLoad={() => {
          createMap();
        }}
        src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.1/mapbox-gl.js"
      />
      <div id="map"></div>
    </>
  );
}
```

1 - If I have multiple instances of `<Map />` on a page, will Next.js load this script multiple times?

**Is there a better way to load this script once, globally and synchronously?** It doesn't seem to work if I load it in my `_document.js` page. Or is this not an issue?

2 - I also have to load the CSS file. Right now I have it loaded on the page that has the map on it.

**pages/contact.js**

```
import Head from 'next/head';

export default function PageContact() {
  return (
    <Head>
      <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </Head>
  );
}
```

If I add maps to other pages, I'd have to include this CSS file on all those other pages, resulting in a lot of duplication. Should I abstract this `<Head>` to its own component and include that on each page?

Or should I be moving this `<Head>` component into the `<Map>` component? It makes sense to centralize this style in one place, but at that point, just like the `<Script>`, I'm guessing Next.js would load the CSS file *each* time the component is instantiated, so if a page had more than one map on it, the CSS would be loaded multiple times.

What is the best way to load Mapbox in a Next.js project?

Comment: The amount of map instances you create isn't necessarily related to loading the script. The script will be loaded once for that page, creating the map instances is then independent from that. Also, I'd recommend keeping the scope of the question to a single problem, to avoid getting it closed as needing more focus.

Comment: Ok, that sounds good. Then I think it could work including the script and CSS inside the Map component, if they only load once. That really isn't obvious to me though. I would think if you include a script in a component and then instantiate the component 3 times, the script would be loaded 3 times. How would I know otherwise? Can you point to some docs somewhere that describe this behaviour?